# Apache Camel Modify ActiveMQ response Message

Tags: xml, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I will try to be a thorough as possible with my explanation:

My use case is to take an XML from ActiveMQ, modify it slightly, and put it on a different ActiveMQ queue where the XML will be picked up by a python script which uses the XML information to build a response XML which will be placed on a different ActiveMQ queue so the response can be slightly modified and then put onto another ActiveMQ queue which serves as the reply queue for the original camel route.

This is what I have so far:

```
<routeBuilder ref="DynamicRouteBuilder"/>
    <route id="sendDCSBatchValues">
        <description>Send</description>
        <from id="_fromActiveMQQueues" uri="direct:queueA?failIfNoConsumers=false"/>
        <log id="logInboundFile" loggingLevel="INFO" message="Inbound File received - ${in.headers.JMSMessageID}"/>
        <setProperty id="_setPropertyArchiveFilename" propertyName="archiveFilename">
            <simple>$simple{camelId}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}-${bean:countr.incrementAndGet}</simple>
        </setProperty>
        <to id="_parseInboundMsg" pattern="InOut" uri="language:groovy:resourceUri?exchangePattern=InOut&amp;script=resource:classpath:parseInboundXML.groovy"/>
        <to id="_logInboundMsg" pattern="OutOnly" uri="file:{{archive.path}}/in?exchangePattern=OutOnly&amp;fileName=$simple{exchange.getProperty(&quot;archiveFilename&quot;).replaceAll(&quot;:&quot;,&quot;-&quot;)}.xml"/>
        <to id="_sendInboundMsg" pattern="InOut" uri="activemq:queue:{{activemq.sending.endpoint}}?exchangePattern=InOut;replyTo=activemq:queue:{{activemq.tempHolding.endpoint}}?exchangePattern=InOut;replyToType=Exclusive"/>
        <onException id="_exception">
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
            <to id="_exceptionQueue" pattern="OutOnly" uri="direct:exceptionCaught?failIfNoConsumers=false"/>
            <log id="logSendException" loggingLevel="ERROR" message="Inbound File Exception - ${in.headers.JMSMessageID}"/>
        </onException>
    </route>
```

As you can see I have the inbound XML and I modify it to my liking, as well as put it onto a "sending" queue. I have set the replyTo queue to be a "tempHolding" queue. The message on the "sending" queue will be picked up by a different application which will use the XML information to build a responding XML. The responding XML will be put on a "receiving" queue where I will pick it up in a second camel route and make modifications to it and finally put it into the "tempHolding" queue so that it can be sent back as a response.

My question is: How do I ensure that the response XML has the correct header information so camel knows it is the response to the original message. I know I need a jmsCorrelationID but when I am debugging the message it does not appear to be set when the message is sent out to the "sending" queue. Would I have to set these properties in the inbound XML message and then pull them out of the response and set them as properties before putting the response XML on the "tempHolding" queue?

Thanks for your help, if there is anything I can verify better, let me know.

**EDIT**

I think it would be helpful for me to post my receiving queue which takes the XML response and modifies it and then puts it back onto the "tempHolding" queue:

```
 <route id="receiveResponse">
        <description>Receive Values</description>
        <from id="_responseMsg" uri="activemq:queue:{{activemq.receiving.endpoint}}?exchangePattern=OutOnly"/>
        <to id="_setArchiveFilename" pattern="InOut" uri="language:groovy:resourceUri?exchangePattern=InOut&amp;script=resource:classpath:setProperties.groovy"/>
        <to id="_logResponseMsg" pattern="OutOnly" uri="file:{{archive.path}}/out?exchangePattern=OutOnly&amp;fileName=$simple{exchange.getProperty(&quot;archiveFilename&quot;).replaceAll(&quot;:&quot;,&quot;-&quot;)}.xml"/>
        <log id="logResponseMsg" loggingLevel="INFO" message="Outbound File Archive - ${in.headers.JMSMessageID}"/>
        <to id="_responseMsgToQueue" pattern="OutOnly" uri="activemq:queue:{{activemq.tempHolding.endpoint}}?exchangePattern=OutOnly"/>
    </route>
```

My originial question is if this is the best way to modify the response XML to ensure that it is returned properly to the inbound message?

Comment: Its a bit hard to follow, but in the `_sendInboundMsg_` you are doing request/reply over JMS, and whomever on the other side is responsible of sending back the reply message on the given `JMSReplyTo` queue with the `JMSCorrelationID`. Whatever happens down that road is outside the responsible of this Camel application.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I have made some edits to include my route which handles the response. Looking at the big picture all I want to know is if this is a valid way to modify a response message and send it back as the reply to the original message?